# Cross-browser XMLHttpRequest with simplifications

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Three Questions:

In the MDN documentation on `XHR`, at *Step 3 - A simple example*, why did they write the code in such a way as to reference every `XMLHttpRequest` via a global variable: `httpRequest`? Does it address some weird browser inconsistencies?

Also, do you think that this is a more idiomatic and concise way of creating an `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
<script type = 'text/javascript' language = 'Javascript' charset = 'utf-8'>

var httpRequest;
var sendStuff = function(url,method) {  
if (!method) {var method = 'POST'}
if (!url) {return}

httpRequest = (function() { // self executing anonymous function
  try {        
    return new XMLHttpRequest() || ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0') 
    || ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0') || ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

    /* equivalent to returning a new instance of XHR OR if false ActiveX 6.0 OR 
       if false ActiveX 3.0 OR if false XMLHTTP, depending on browser support */
  } 
  catch(e) { return } // handle errors: if no support
})();
</script>
```

**Edit**: Apparently, the `(function(){})()` thing doesn't seem to be necessary upon peer review. Just use `httpRequest = a || b || c || d || false`;

**Edit2**: Unfortunately, IE will apparently throw an error if ActiveX is disabled regardless, so stick with the `try-catch`.

```
<script>

if (httpRequest) {
httpRequest.open(method,url);
httpRequest.send(null);
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
        alert(httpRequest.responseText);        
    }   
};
} 
else { 
if (document.getElementById) {
    document.getElementById('fallback').innerHTML = 'No XHR support!'
} else { alert('Jeez - time for an upgrade, dude!'); }
}

}; // end sendStuff

</script>
```

Seems like it would be a little bit easier to understand that way, as long as everyone understood the syntax. Is this true for you?

Finally, does the `ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')` predate the other IE `XHR`s, or should it be used in preference of `Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0`?

**Notes**: If you're using XAMPP/localhost, IE in protected mode may prevent your scripts from running in the first place. You will have to check `enable scripts` in protected mode to test XHR there.

I researched some more and wanted to post my own answer before anyone wasted their time trying out the program, but I actually cannot until tomorrow, so it goes here ->

*Question One*: Using a global variable as `XHR` limits simultaneous Ajax requests - to just one, in fact, as the previous `XHR` would be overwritten. This can be a useful effect, though not always. Use local variables instead if you want to allow concurrent requests, though the exact number varies between browsers.

*Question Three*: Already Answered.

*Question Two*: Unfortunately, using the OR operator will still throw an error as soon as the browser reaches a feature that it doesn't recognize. Example:

```
var testIng = fakeFunction() || otherFakeFunction() || true; 
console.log(testIng);

// Uncaught Reference Error for fakeFunction()
```

So, while using `||` may be more concise, it is at the expense of the application. This however, works with no exceptions:

```
var testIng = (function() {
try {
    return new fakeFunction();  
} 
catch (e) {
    return true;
}
})();

console.log(testIng); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable is only global because the entire script runs in the global context.

It is used because you need to work with an *instance* of the object, and not the raw constructor function.

Wrapping the code which creates that instance in a self-executing anonymous function is pointless. There are no variables created that aren't returned to the global scope.

---

> does the ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') predate the other IE XHRs

Yes.

> or should it be used in preference of Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0?

Native XMLHttpRequest has been supported since IE7. I've given up worrying about IE older than IE 8, so I wouldn't fall back to ActiveX at all. (Your mileage and target audience may vary).

Comment: Well with IE8 you can disable native XMLHttpRequest support so the ActiveX rollback is sort of needed. I know of organizations that had that freaking box unchecked so it would use the ActiveX...lol

Comment: You're right, no self-executing function necessary, with an extra OR false to prevent errors.

Comment: And hey, MDN used ActiveX as well in their example documentation. That's got to count for something.

Comment: Actually the self executing function is sort of needed with the try catch. If ActiveX is disabled, the browser still says it supports it, but it throws an error when called.

Comment: Really? So coding: `httpRequest = a || b || c || d || false` won't always work?

Comment: It works, just wonderful IE will throw an error when it is called. hence the try catch...